# Eglot/pyright on Windows is sending malformed paths to the server

Tags: python, eglot

I'm getting all kinds of strange behavior trying to run Eglot with Pyright on Windows with Emacs 29.0.60 ((build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2023-03-10). The `*Messages*` buffer shows lots of attempts to connect, quickly followed by timeouts and server shutdowns. For example,

```
[eglot] Connected! Server `EGLOT (kalman/(python-mode python-ts-mode))' now managing `(python-mode python-ts-mode)' buffers in project `kalman'.
[eglot] Connected! Server `EGLOT (core/(python-mode python-ts-mode))' now managing `(python-mode python-ts-mode)' buffers in project `core'.
[jsonrpc] Server exited with status 1
[eglot] (warning) Not auto-reconnecting, last one didn't last long.
```

Doing `M-x eglot-events-buffer` shows JSON messages with apparently bad URIs for files such as `:uri "file:///c%3A/Users/...`.

```
[client-request] (id:4) Tue May  9 15:55:35 2023:
(:jsonrpc "2.0" :id 4 :method "textDocument/documentHighlight" :params
          (:textDocument
           (:uri "file:///c%3A/Users/rdprice/Apps/msys64/home/rdprice/working/kalman/src/kepler/rotators.py")
           :position
           (:line 27 :character 51)))
```

```
[internal] (id:4) Tue May  9 15:55:45 2023:
(:timed-out :textDocument/documentHighlight :id 4 :params
            (:textDocument
             (:uri "file:///c%3A/Users/rdprice/Apps/msys64/home/rdprice/working/kalman/src/kepler/rotators.py")
             :position
             (:line 27 :character 51)))
```

Is this known behavior? Some mis-configuration on my part?

Here's my Eglot setup:

```
  (use-package eglot
    :ensure t
    :after conda
    :defer t
    :preface
    (defun mp-eglot-eldoc ()
      (setq eldoc-documentation-strategy
            'eldoc-documentation-compose-eagerly))
    :custom
    (eglot-connect-timeout 120)   ; my work computer is slow, slow, slow
    (eglot-stay-out-of 'company)
    (eglot-report-progress t)
    :hook ((eglot-managed-mode . mp-eglot-eldoc)
           (python-mode . eglot-ensure)))
```

**Edit:**

Evaluated in the scratch buffer, the following gives a malformed path,

```
(eglot--path-to-uri ".")
"file:///c%3A/Users/rdprice/Apps/msys64/home/rdprice"
```

Still in the scratch buffer, just to get a valid path, I evaluate

```
(file-truename ".")
"c:/Users/rdprice/Apps/msys64/home/rdprice"
```

Calling this function is basically the first thing that `eglot--path-to-uri` does. Evaluating the following gives me a malformed path,

```
(url-hexify-string
 (file-truename ".")
 eglot--uri-path-allowed-chars)
"c%3A/Users/rdprice/Apps/msys64/home/rdprice"
```

The variable `eglot--uri-path-allowed-chars` is an array of 256 elements, each with value `nil`. The function `url-hexify-string` is called within `eglot--path-to-uri` before tacking on `file:///` to the front.

**Another edit**

It seems that Firefox understands the URI,

```
file:///c%3A/Users/rdprice/Apps/msys64/home/rdprice
```

Perhaps I'm just running down a rabbit hole.